# Перегрузка оператора сравнения своего класса в C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, c++builder, перегрузка-операторов

Пытаюсь перегрузить оператор сравнения своего класса:

```
class Square {
 int x;
 // some data
 public:
  // some methods
  int getX() {return x;}
  bool operator== (Square &sq);
};

bool Square::operator== (Square &sq) {
 int x1 = this->getX();
 int x2 = (&sq)->getX();
 if (x1 == x2) return true;
 return false;
}
```

Но при попытке вызова сравнение работает некорректно. Ошибки не вылетают, но получить истину нельзя. Для теста убирала из оператора все, кроме возврата, но даже так истины не случалось:

```
bool Square::operator== (Square &sq) {
 return true;
}
```

Думала, проблема в том, что программа не видит перегрузки, но если дописать второй параметр, builder начинает ругаться `E2080 'Square::operator== (Square &, Square &)' must be declared with one parameter`. Получается, перегрузку видит, но не пользуется...

Вызов:

```
Square *square1 = new Square();
Square *square2 = new Square();
if (square1 == square2) {
 // some code
}
```

Comment: Изучите тему указателей. Это краеугольный камень, без понимания которого ваше изучение ООП абсолютно бесполезно. Сначала чистый Си с его чисто структурным (процедурным) кодом и указателями, а так же `struct`. Потом Плюсы с его ООП в виде классов, а потом уже все остальное: шаблоны и функциональщина. Так по нормальному нужно подходить к изучению Плюсов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сравниваете указатели, а не объекты класса.

Можно сделать так: `*square1 == *square2`.

Но лучше убрать ненужный `new` и делать вот так:

```
Square square1;
Square square2;
if (square1 == square2) {...}
```

---

Еще, забыт `const` в нескольких местах. Правильно так:

```
int getX() const {return x;}
bool operator==(const Square &sq) const;
```

---

Еще, вот это:

```
int x1 = this->getX();
int x2 = (&sq)->getX();
if (x1 == x2) return true;
return false;
```

Упрощается до `return getX() == sq.getX();`

---

И еще, в современном C++ можно вписать в класс вот такую волшебную конструкцию:

```
friend auto operator<=>(const Square &, const Square &) = default;
```

И автоматически сгенерировать все 6 операторов сравнения: `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` - чтобы не писать их руками.